# Command button with 'paste date' function to its next left cell

Tags: button, excel, command, cell, vba

I'd like to create a `Commandbutton` with functionality to paste a date in to the cell to its left - I need to copy this button below in future.

I am trying:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim Str As String
    Str = Date
    Range(TopLeftCell).Value = Str
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean if the button is placed on top of say D5 then you need the date in C5 ?

Comment: Exactly - need button to add actual date to left cell next to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `Form Control` instead of `ActiveX control` and the reason is very simple. **When you copy the button across, the link to the macro remains intact.**, which is also one of your requirements.

And this is the code that you can use for the CommandButton (Form Control)

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim cellAddr As String
    Dim aCol As Long

    '~~> Get the address of the cell
    cellAddr = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address
    '~~> Also get the column number
    aCol = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column

    '~~> This is required if the button is in column 1
    If aCol <> 1 Then _
    ActiveSheet.Range(cellAddr).Offset(, -1).Value = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3090201: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: +1 for point about advantage of `Form` control over `ActiveX` control

Answer (score 0):

To point at a specific range do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Str As String
    Str = Date
    Range("C5").Value = Str

End Sub
```

Alternatively use a named range i.e. give the `range` C5 the name "TopLeftCell"

[image]

...then you can use the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Str As String
    Str = Date
    Range("TopLeftCell").Value = Str

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
Dim str As String
    r = Rows.Count
    c = Columns.Count
    str = Date
    For i = 1 To r
        If Cells(i, 1).Top > CommandButton2.Top Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    r = i - 1 ' you have to calibrate, what fits better r = i or r = i - 1 or r = i - 2 ....
    For i = 1 To c
        If Cells(1, i).Left > CommandButton2.Left Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    c = i - 2 ' you have to calibrate, what fits better c = i or c = i - 1 or c = i - 2 ....
    Cells(r, c) = str
End Sub
```

This should work, but it really depends on where you place the button. Look at the lines `r = i - 1` and `c = i - 2`.